# How to use a correct HQL in NamedQuery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a doubt and problem how to use a correct HQL in NamedQueries, I read many articles and I make some test in my project, but I have a problem, I don't know why I have this problem, for me its all ok,  see the stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/EMS2App] threw exception [java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: ProjectMediator.findProjectByIdProjectMediator, Project.findProjectWithStatus
```

ProjectMediator class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMediator.findProjectByIdProjectMediator",
                query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMediator pm WHERE pm.project.id := idProject") 
                        })

public class ProjectMediator implements Serializable {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String FIND_PROJECT_BY_ID_PROJECTMEDIATOR = "ProjectMediator.findProjectByIdProjectMediator";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_project")
private Project project;
```

ProjectMediatorDAO class:

```
public class ProjectMediatorDAO extends GenericDAO<ProjectMediator>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProjectMediatorDAO () {
        super(ProjectMediator.class);
    }

    public ProjectMediator findProjectByIdProjectMediator (int idProject) {
        Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parameters.put("idProject",idProject);
        return super.findOneResult(ProjectMediator.FIND_PROJECT_BY_ID_PROJECTMEDIATOR, parameters);
    }
}
```

Is the same problem for the Project class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries ({
    @NamedQuery (name="Project.findProjectWithStatus",query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.statusProject := statusProject"),
})
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FIND_PROJECT_WITH_STATUS = "Project.findProjectWithStatus";

    //Attributes
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="STATUS_PROJECT",columnDefinition="BIT", length=1)
    private Boolean statusProject;
  //gets and sets
}
```

ProjectDAO class:

```
public class ProjectDAO extends GenericDAO<Project> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProjectDAO() {
        super(Project.class);
    }

    public List<Project> findProjectWithStatus(Boolean statusProject) {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("statusProject", statusProject);
        return super.findManyResult(Project.FIND_PROJECT_WITH_STATUS,parameters);
    }

}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the HQL is off.  The `:` comes before the parameter and the `=` is part of the static query.

Change:

```
SELECT pm FROM ProjectMediator pm WHERE pm.project.id := idProject
```

to

```
SELECT pm FROM ProjectMediator pm WHERE pm.project.id = :idProject
```

This issue also exists in your second HQL query.

```
 @NamedQuery (name="Project.findProjectWithStatus",
     query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.statusProject := statusProject")
```

**Corrected Form**

```
 @NamedQuery (name="Project.findProjectWithStatus",
    query="SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.statusProject = :statusProject")
```

Comment: Good! I make a big mistake with the `:=`. It's work, thank you!